# Change variable defined in let function

Tags: lisp, let

Given the following let function:

```
(let ((foo (list a b c d)))
foo)
```

How can i modify the list foo?

```
(let ((foo (list a b c d)))
;some code
foo)
```

so the returned foo looks like eks: '(some new list) or (a b modified d)

i tried (set) but foo will still return as the original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setf` to modify a specific element in a list.

```
(let ((foo (list 'a 'b 'c 'd)))
  (setf (third foo) 'modified)
  foo)
```

This will return `(a b modified d)`.

Or if you want to replace the whole variable, you can assign directly to it with `setq`:

```
(let ((foo (list 'a 'b 'c 'd)))
  (setq foo (list 'some 'new 'list))
  foo)
```

You can't use `set` with lexical variables, only special variables.